# error in getting post id

Tags: functions

I am making a voting system

The problem is that the post id Is returning blank

I am sure that post id is returning blank

Bcoz when I put a real post id value there it seems working

For example

```
update_post_meta(123, "votes" , $newvotes)
```

Is Working properly

But

```
 update_post_meta($postid, "votes" , $newvotes)
```

isn't working properly

here is the code

```
  add_action("wp_ajax_add_votes_options", "add_votes_options"); 
  add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_add_votes_options", "add_votes_options");
  function add_votes_options() {
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'voting_nonce'))
    return;

$postid = $_POST['postid'];
$ip = $_POST['ip'];

$voter_ips = get_post_meta($postid, "voter_ips", true);
if(!empty($voter_ips) && in_array($ip, $voter_ips)) {
    echo "null";
    die(0);
} else {
    $voter_ips[] = $ip;
    update_post_meta($postid, "voter_ips", $voter_ips);
}   

$current_votes = get_post_meta($postid, "votes", true);
$new_votes = $current_votes + 1;
update_post_meta($postid, "votes", $new_votes);
$return = $new_votes>1 ? $new_votes." votes" : $new_votes." vote";
echo $return;
die(0);
    }
```

AND ALSO I TRIED THIS

```
add_action("wp_ajax_add_votes_options", "add_votes_options");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_add_votes_options", "add_votes_options");
function add_votes_options() {
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'voting_nonce'))
    return;

$postid = $_POST['postid'];
$ip = $_POST['ip'];

$voter_ips = get_post_meta($_REQUEST["post_id"], "voter_ips", true);
if(!empty($voter_ips) && in_array($ip, $voter_ips)) {
    echo "null";
    die(0);
} else {
    $voter_ips[] = $ip;
    update_post_meta($_REQUEST["post_id"], "voter_ips", $voter_ips);
}   

$current_votes = get_post_meta($_REQUEST["post_id"], "votes", true);
$new_votes = intval($current_votes) + 1;
update_post_meta($_REQUEST["post_id"], "votes", $new_votes);
$return = $new_votes>1 ? $new_votes." votes" : $new_votes." vote";
echo $return;
die(0);
    }
```

But none of this codes are working

EDIT#1
 calling my action at jQuery

```
$("#vote").not(".disabled").click(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    el.html('<span id="loader"></span>');
    var nonce = $("input#voting_nonce").val();
    var data = {
        action: 'add_votes_options',
        nonce: nonce,
        postid: '<?php echo $post->ID; ?>,',
        ip: '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>'            
    };
```

Comment: What values do you get whe you `print_r` your `$_POST` parameters? Is everything correct there?

Comment: Yes. But still post id is returning blank

Comment: Could you please add the output of your `print_r` to your question, so I can take a look at it?

Comment: Am in my mobile so I can't add there .is there any other way to get post id

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help if I have to guess about the information..

Comment: if post id isn't being passed then it would logically seem that it isn't getting set in your javascript function to begin with: `postid: '<?php echo $post->ID; ?>,'`. also look at [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) for passing data to javascript.

Answer (score 4):

On a default install of WP you get always the ID of a post with the function `get_the_ID()`. Id dosnt work this you go about the global var: `$post`.

```
echo $GLOBALS['post']->ID
```

Is this not enough, then go about the global wp_query

```
$GLOBALS['wp_query']->post->ID;
```

Comment: Get_the_id() functions only works within the loop

Comment: right, for outside the loop the other variants.

Comment: You are right @bueltge, but as far as I got this question, the ID comes from an AJAX call, so it won't be set.

Comment: It isn't working @bueltge

Comment: @fischi  please check the edit may it help you

Comment: See the edit the post id is now coming properly when I saw its source

Comment: If the ID comes from a AJAX call, then use JSON to send/read the dat, the ID.

Comment: The problem was bcoz I was running a query in single.php whoh was causing problems